# Comparing 2 lists of dates and counting if deliverables were on time

Tags: excel, vba, date, count, countif

I am looking to compare a list of scheduled dates vs. dates when a deliverable was sent. If the sent date is less than or equal to the scheduled date, i want to count it as "on time". If the sent date is after the scheduled date, i want to count it as "LAte"

```
ITEM    Scheduled Date  SentDate
A   9/20/2018   9/20/2019
B   9/20/2018   1/5/2023
C   9/20/2018   2/2/2022
D   9/20/2018   7/3/2021
```

---

```
 Sub datetest()

Range("A10") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(C:C),"> B")

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("A10") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C:C"),">" & Range("B:B"))`

Comment: Thank you Scott. I am able to get this to work for a single date comparison. So i can compare C2 to B2. When i use the range C:C and B:B, it errors out

Comment: yes, sorry.  It would be best if you mass load the used ranges into variant arrays, then loop those arrays and do the compare yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yo do it with array formulas:

```
range("A10").FormulaArray = "=SUM(--(B2:B5<C2:C5))" 'Whatever range you need
```